# Calculus residue backsustitution

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, complex

I try to calculate `f[z_] := Coth[z]/( E^z - 1)^1`
and calculate

```
Reduce[(f[z])^-1 == 0, z, GeneratedParameters -> (k &)] // FullSimplify
```

and gives

```
k \[Element] Integers && (z == 2 I k \[Pi] || z == I k \[Pi])
```

now i try to pass the poles to the residue to calculate

```
Table[Residue[f[z],{z,k1}],{k1,{2I \[Pi] k,-I \[Pi] k,-2I \[Pi] k,I \[Pi] k}}]
```

it is possible to backsustitution in the table above automatically 
thanks anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

like this?

```
sol = FullSimplify@Assuming[C[1] \[Element] Integers, 
Simplify@Solve[Simplify@Reduce[ComplexExpand@(f[z]^-1) == 0, z], z]]

Assuming[ C[1] \[Element] Integers,FullSimplify@Residue[f[z], Evaluate@{z, z /. sol[[1]]}]]

(* -1/2 *)
```

I think that here it is assumed it is known `C[1]` is an integer. So, I suggest to look at what `Reduce` returns to be sure.

Comment: Jose Antonio how to calculate the result when k is negative or positive apart

Comment: But the solution includes all the integers isn't it? So the result is valid for negative as well as positive integers. I think you could use `C[1] \[Element] Integers && C[1] > 0` or `C[1] \[Element] Integers && C[1] < 0` in `Assuming`

Comment: Jose alreadyy test your solution but the Residue at poles when k is positive is not the same at k negative reduce not discriminate the solution when k is posivite the pole the residue y bot the same in z=2k i  that in z=.-2 k i it is posible to get thos to solution apart above but i need that reduce separate C[1] in interger + and - thanks anyway

Comment: $$\frac{\csc (x)}{e^{\pi  x}-1}=-\sum _{k=1}^{\infty } \frac{(-1)^k x^2}{\pi  \left(e^{\pi ^2 k}-1\right) k (\pi  k-x) (\pi  k+x)}-\frac{(-1)^k x^3}{\pi ^2 \left(e^{\pi ^2 k}-1\right) k^2 (\pi  k-x) (\pi  k+x)}+\frac{(-1)^k e^{\pi ^2 k} x^3}{\pi ^2 \left(e^{\pi ^2 k}-1\right) k^2 (\pi  k-x) (\pi  k+x)}-\frac{x^2 \text{csch}(k) \text{sech}(k)}{2 \pi  k \left(4 k^2+x^2\right)}-\frac{(-1)^k e^{\pi ^2 k} x^2}{\pi  \left(e^{\pi ^2 k}-1\right) k (\pi  k-x) (\pi  k+x)}+\frac{1}{\pi  x^2}-\frac{x}{12}-\frac{1}{2 x}+\frac{2+\pi ^2}{12 \pi }$$ reduce not  separate C[1] + or - i need to series as above

Comment: I think the result is correct as the MacLaurin Series gives the value $-1/2$ for the coefficient of $1/(z-z_0)$ independently of the sign of the integer `C[1]`

Comment: not  using interger + you get $$\frac{x^2 \left(\coth \left(\pi ^2 k\right)-1\right)}{8 \pi ^2 k^2 (2 \pi  k-x)}+\frac{x^2 \text{csch}(2 k)}{8 \pi  k^3+4 i \pi  k^2 x}-\frac{x^2}{\left(e^{\pi ^2 (2 k+1)}-1\right) (2 \pi  k+\pi )^2 (2 \pi  k-x+\pi )}$$ it miss the interger - at least you calculate by hand